# Spring Boot exported jar not working (org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory')

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jar, spring-boot

We have been working on project which works fine when we run it in the (Intellij) ide. But when we export the the spring boot project as a jar file, it no longer works

```
    21:33:06.495 [main] INFO  demo.TrainsFromApplication - Starting TrainsFromApplication on macbook-pro with PID 1955 (/Users/sauravskumar/IdeaProjects/TrainsFrom/out/artifacts/TrainsFrom_jar/TrainsFrom.jar started by sauravskumar in /Users/sauravskumar/IdeaProjects/TrainsFrom/out/artifacts/TrainsFrom_jar)
21:33:06.687 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@23282c25: startup date [Sun Aug 23 21:33:06 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
21:33:09.528 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
21:33:10.660 [main] INFO  o.h.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
21:33:10.941 [main] WARN  demo.TrainsFromApplication - No Spring profile configured, running with default configuration
21:33:10.941 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'trainsFromApplication' of type [class demo.TrainsFromApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e78db5e1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
21:33:10.942 [main] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Initialising PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor
21:33:11.143 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5c0f18ac] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
21:33:12.005 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @10510ms
21:33:12.376 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory - Server initialized with port: 8080
21:33:12.380 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.2.11.v20150529
21:33:12.678 [main] INFO  application - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
21:33:12.678 [main] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6046 ms
21:33:14.305 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
21:33:14.348 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
21:33:14.359 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
21:33:14.360 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'simpleCORSFilter' to: [/*]
21:33:14.361 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@5c5d6175{/,null,AVAILABLE}
21:33:14.361 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @12866ms
21:33:15.233 [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
21:33:15.302 [main] INFO  o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
21:33:15.558 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
21:33:15.562 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
21:33:15.566 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
21:33:15.637 [main] WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1011) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:802) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:521) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M1.jar:1.3.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:678) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M1.jar:1.3.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:339) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M1.jar:1.3.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:274) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M1.jar:1.3.0.M1]
    at demo.TrainsFromApplication.main(TrainsFromApplication.java:119) [TrainsFrom.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.getValidationMode(PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.java:99) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.mergePropertySources(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:569) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
21:33:15.755 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Stopped o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@5c5d6175{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}
21:33:15.758 [main] INFO  o.s.b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Users/sauravskumar/IdeaProjects/TrainsFrom/out/artifacts/TrainsFrom_jar/TrainsFrom.jar]
21:33:15.758 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1011) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:802) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:521) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.M1.jar:1.3.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:678) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.M1.jar:1.3.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.M1.jar:1.3.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:274) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.M1.jar:1.3.0.M1]
    at demo.TrainsFromApplication.main(TrainsFromApplication.java:119) [TrainsFrom.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.getValidationMode(PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.java:99) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.mergePropertySources(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:569) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:802)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:521)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:678)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:274)
    at demo.TrainsFromApplication.main(TrainsFromApplication.java:119)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.getValidationMode(PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.mergePropertySources(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:188)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 14 more
```

The pom.xml file is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.test</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>trains_from</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.M1</version>
    <!--<version>1.3.0.M3</version>-->
    <!--<relativePath/> &lt;!&ndash; lookup parent from repository &ndash;&gt;-->
</parent>

<properties>
    <neo4j.version>2.2.4</neo4j.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <!--<springdatacommons.version>1.11.0.RC1</springdatacommons.version>-->
    <springdatacommons.version>1.11.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</springdatacommons.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>redis.clients</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>jedis</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>2.7.2</version>-->
        <!--<type>jar</type>-->
        <!--<scope>compile</scope>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring-data-neo4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>${springdatacommons.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>${neo4j.version}</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.voodoodyne.jackson.jsog</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jsog</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
        <!--<type>test-jar</type>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

    <!--REST-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.json</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>json</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>20141113</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>1.1.1</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>2.4.0</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20141113</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-io</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!--<configuration>-->
                <!--<mainClass>demo.TrainsFromApplication</mainClass>-->
            <!--</configuration>-->
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>neo4j</id>
        <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>

    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>

    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>

</pluginRepositories>

<!--<repositories>-->
    <!--<repository>-->
        <!--<id>spring-snapshots</id>-->
        <!--<name>Spring Snapshots</name>-->
        <!--<url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>-->
        <!--<snapshots>-->
            <!--<enabled>true</enabled>-->
        <!--</snapshots>-->
    <!--</repository>-->
    <!--<repository>-->
        <!--<id>spring-milestones</id>-->
        <!--<name>Spring Milestones</name>-->
        <!--<url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>-->
        <!--<snapshots>-->
            <!--<enabled>false</enabled>-->
        <!--</snapshots>-->
    <!--</repository>-->
<!--</repositories>-->
<!--<pluginRepositories>-->
    <!--<pluginRepository>-->
        <!--<id>spring-snapshots</id>-->
        <!--<name>Spring Snapshots</name>-->
        <!--<url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>-->
        <!--<snapshots>-->
            <!--<enabled>true</enabled>-->
        <!--</snapshots>-->
    <!--</pluginRepository>-->
    <!--<pluginRepository>-->
        <!--<id>spring-milestones</id>-->
        <!--<name>Spring Milestones</name>-->
        <!--<url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>-->
        <!--<snapshots>-->
            <!--<enabled>false</enabled>-->
        <!--</snapshots>-->
    <!--</pluginRepository>-->
<!--</pluginRepositories>-->
```

```
# application.properties file is


spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/trains_from_test


spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =


spring.jpa.show-sql = true


spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none


spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

when we replace the

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.M1</version> 
</parent>
```

in pom.xml with

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.M2</version> 
</parent>
```

The error changes to: -

```
  macbook-pro:TrainsFrom_jar sauravskumar$ java -jar TrainsFrom.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/support/PersistenceExceptionTranslator
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3040)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3010)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1776)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Disclaimer: We have also tried

```
  <properties>
            <neo4j.version>2.2.4</neo4j.version>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <springdatacommons.version>1.11.0.RC1</springdatacommons.version>
            <!--<springdatacommons.version>1.11.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</springdatacommons.version>-->
        </properties>
```

But the output error is the same as the second error. Thank You in advance!

Comment: The first error is telling you that you've got an incompatible version of the JPA API on the classpath. You could use `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out where it's coming from

Comment: But the thing works fine in the ide. Only when we export it as a jar, we come across errors. Can you please help us with the problem? Thank You in advance.

Comment: Using mvn dependency:tree gives a Build success, but when we try to run it using mvn spring-boot:run, same error as in case1 occurs. Thank you!

Comment: I need the output from `mvn dependency:tree` to help further. Knowing what's in your jar (output from `unzip -l`, for example) would also help.

Comment: I have tried pasting the output of mvn dependency:tree but the output is too long for stack overflow to be posted. Can you please tell me some other way to send you the output. Thank You in advance!

Comment: You could use something like [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) or create a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/)

Comment: @andy-wilkinson Dear Sir, we have pasted the mvn dependency:tree log in the [GITHUB MVN DEPENDENCY:TREE Link](https://github.com/orngex/trainsFrom/blob/master/mvn%20dependecy:tree) at github. Please help us if you can. Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two different JPA API jars on the classpath. One for JPA 1.0 and one for JPA 2.1. You need to exclude the JPA 1.0 jar from the classpath. From Maven's output, you can see that it's a dependency of `spring-data-neo4j`:

```
+- org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.0.RC1:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.0.RC1:compile
|  \- javax.persistence:com.springsource.javax.persistence:jar:1.0.0:compile
```

You need to update the Spring Data Neo4J dependency in your pom to exclude the JPA API:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RC1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.persistence</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Dear Sir, We are very much thankful to you for your kind help. Thank You again.