# Hibernate cannot create entityManagerFactory bean in compiled jar with Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am running into a very strange issue here and I think it might be related to this SO post: [Spring Boot exported jar not working (org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168833/spring-boot-exported-jar-not-working-org-springframework-beans-factory-beancrea). However I cannot map the answer to my exact case.

When I run my project from IntelliJ IDE it works fine and when I compile it as a jar (and run it on Docker Cloud) I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Properties;
```

The relevant part ist this I think: 
 `org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Properties;`

I tried cleaning the build directory and building again, but the error persists in the jar file. Googling around I found multiple posts suggesting that it is an old version of JPA not working with the current hibernate version.

This is my current gradle build file: 
        group 'com.energiedienst.smartcity.middleware'
        version '0.1'

```
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: "idea"
    apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-java-application'
    apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

    import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.*

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    ext {
        springCloudVersion = '1.2.1.RELEASE'
        jettyVersion = '9.4.2.v20170220'
        jacksonVersion = '2.8.8'
        springSecurityVersion = '4.2.3.RELEASE'
        springBootVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE'

        dockerBaseImage = getProperty('docker.baseImage')
        dockerRegistryUrl = getProperty('docker.registry.url')
        dockerRegistryName = getProperty('docker.registry.name')
        dockerRegistryUsername = getProperty('docker.registry.username')
        dockerRegistryPassword = getProperty('docker.registry.password')
    }

    configurations {
        runtimeOnly
        all {
            exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
            exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        }
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:3.0.11'
            classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:${springBootVersion}")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${springBootVersion}")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:${springBootVersion}")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:${springBootVersion}")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:${springBootVersion}")

        compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: jacksonVersion
        compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: jacksonVersion
        compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-yaml', version: jacksonVersion
        compile 'com.bedatadriven:jackson-datatype-jts:2.2'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5:2.9.0'

        compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-security-oauth2', version: '2.0.12.RELEASE'

        compile group: 'com.github.paulcwarren', name: 'spring-content-s3-boot-starter', version: '0.0.5'
        compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.6'
        compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.10.Final'
        compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-spatial', version: '5.2.10.Final'

        compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'

        compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.5'

        compile group: 'org.reflections', name: 'reflections', version: '0.9.10'

        compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.16.16'

        testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
        testCompile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    }
    //..... docker build stuff from here
```

If I grep for persistence however it doesn't seem like there are different versions in there

```
Azalea ::  » gradle dependencies|grep persistence           1 ↵
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
```

Any idea how to debug this, am I completely on the wrong path here?

Cheers and thx.

Comment: Did you follow [https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html)?

Comment: @rnavagamuwa anything in specific I don't see? It's a pretty general guide on how to use gradle in spring boot. Can't find anything relating to managing / troubleshooting dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The smell was right,... it worked locally because from somewhere the hibernate-jpa jar was in my classpath and got resolven when I started it from IntelliJ. I have the feeling IntelliJ is using hibernate for the database plugin.

Adding

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: hibernateVersion
compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: '1.0.0.Final'
```

fixed the problem. I think `hibernate-entitymanager` is responsible for the fix. After checking `gradle dependencies` I saw I had a `5.0.x` version of entitymanager loaded (whyever...) which is not compatible with JPA2.  Adding the explicit dependency loaded the right version into the jar.

Comment: can you spell out what your hibernateVersion variable value is?

Comment: People who stumble on this question.  I had an issue that was after the entityFactoryManager error (make sure you look at the entire stack).  Mine was resolved :     /* need this line to avoid Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.search.Filter on built .jar */
    implementation group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'lucene-core', version: luceneCoreVersion. (I had 5.5.5 for my version).   but my "fix" came as a direct result of looking what came after the error on this question.  your (later) error may vary.